# How to preload imageView's height and width attribute?

Tags: android

When using a recycleView with many images, Glide takes a while to load the image for the first time, how can I preload the image's height and width by setting the imageView to that size before using glide to load it in?

```
Glide.with(mContext)
      .load(link)
      .apply(RequestOptions.centerInsideTransform())
      .into(holder.vhImageView);
```

[image]

Reddit also does it this way

Comment: Do the images have different sizes? like @Chad said you can use placeholders 
https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/placeholders.html also you can use caching
https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/caching.html

Comment: The placeholders for Glide are the same size as the loaded image. Does caching get the size of the image before it's loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glide may have an equivalent method, but I use Picasso, and you can set a .placeHolder(R.drawable.placeholder) image that will be in place until the image actually loads.

You could assign holder.vhImageView a default image in xml that should also work as a placeholder as long as Glide doesn't clear it as it's loading the new image?

You could set a minHeight on the holder.vhImageView in XML but that can cause problems if the views loaded end up being shorter than that.